# Get image using a persisted face-id

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have reached the point in my programming where I would like to be able to view the image with a given face ID. Does the face api support this in anyway, or will I need to find a way to associate face id's with image urls beforehand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Face API does not support this and you need to do it by yourself.

Due to **legal limitations**, Face API does not support images retrieval in any circumstance currently. You need to store the images and maintain the relationship between face ids and images by yourself.

Feel free to update in case of any further related problem.